# How to join two ON conditions on the same field

Tags: mysql, join

I have one table_A

```
|  id  | status1 | status2 | 
+------+---------+---------+
|   1  |     2   |    3    |
+------+---------+---------+
|   2  |     1   |    3    |
+------+---------+---------+
```

and table_B

```
|  id  |  name   |  
+------+---------+
|   1  |   yep   | 
+------+---------+
|   2  |   nope  |   
+------+---------+
|   3  |   maybe |   
+------+---------+
```

How can I get the output to look like this?

> 1 =nope,  maybe;
>   2 =yep,  maybe

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A a 
LEFT JOIN table_B b 
ON a.status1= b.id AND a.status2= b.id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do two joins, one for each status field:

```
SELECT a.id, b1.name as name1, b2.name
FROM table_A  a LEFT JOIN
     table_B b1 
     ON a.status1 = b1.id LEFT JOIN
     table_B b2
     on a.status2= b2.id;
```

EDIT:

For amusement's sake, you can do this with one join and aggregation:

```
select a.id,
       max(case when a.status1 = b.id then b.name end) as name1,
       max(case when a.status2 = b.id then b.name end) as name2
from table_A a left join
     table_B b
     on b.id in (a.status1, a.status2)
group by a.id;
```

However, the two-join version is actually simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A  a 
LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.status1= b.id 
LEFT JOIN table_B bTmp ON a.status2= bTmp.id
```

Comment: Ok there's no problem!

Best Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a column to be exactly `yep, maybe` and `nope, maybe`, you'll need the [`GROUP_CONCAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

You can get away with one join if you "un-pivot" your `table_a`, which is what the subquery in my answer does:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY b.name DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT id, status1 AS stat_id FROM table_a
  UNION SELECT id, status2 FROM table_a
) a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.stat_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

The `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` makes sure `yep` comes before `maybe` and that `nope` comes before `maybe` in the comma-separated list.

Comment: thank you for you clear explanation. No I do not need exactly output like that, it was just example to understand it.  I accepted Gordons answer as he was faster ;).

Comment: You're welcome, and no worries - when all the answers help it's right to accept the fastest :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, b1.name, b2.name from tableB as b1
inner join TableA as a
on b1.id = a.status1
inner join TableB as b2
on b2.id = a.status2
```